# Returning distinct columns from left outer join in db2

Tags: db2

```
SELECT
    nzy.NZPYYD
    ,nzy.NZZSYG
    ,nzy.NZJRYG
        ,acn.ANITCD

FROM
    ACNTRA acn

        LEFT OUTER JOIN NZYTFL nzy
            ON (
                nzy.NZCNO1 = acn.ANCNO1
                AND nzy.NZCNO2 = acn.ANCNO2
                AND nzy.NZCNO3 = acn.ANCNO3
                AND nzy.NZCNO4 = acn.ANCNO4
                AND nzy.NZCNO5 = acn.ANCNO5
                AND nzy.NZSLKI = acn.ANSLKI
                AND nzy.NZDLTM = ''
            )

                                WHERE
                                    acn.ANDLTM = ''
                                    AND acn.ANTKCD = '1029'
                                    AND nzy.NZTXKB = 1
```

The problem here is it gives 2 rows result.I want to get one unique row from the result of left outer join .Any help?

Answer (score 0):

If both rows are identical, try

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    nzy.NZPYYD
    ,nzy.NZZSYG
    ,nzy.NZJRYG
        ,acn.ANITCD
```

If not, you can try to `SUM()`, `CONCAT()`, `MAX()` or whatever the column with different values.

Difficult to be more precise without a sample output.

Comment: But i want distinct from the result of left outer join.The table NZYTFL has unique key UNIQUE (NZCNO1, NZCNO2, NZCNO3, NZCNO4, NZCNO5, NZSLKI, NZTXKB, NZSyur).But ACNTRA has  UNIQUE (ANCNO1, ANCNO2, ANCNO3, ANCNO4, ANCNO5, ANSLKI).So,if acntra has one row with key values in  ANCNO1, ANCNO2, ANCNO3, ANCNO4, ANCNO5, ANSLKI then NZYTFL has two rows with same key value . So,it gives one more extra rows which is unnessary.

Comment: NZYTFL table 
YLCNO1, YLCNO2, YLCNO3, YLCNO4, YLCNO5, YLSLKI, YLTAXC, YLSQNO 
1         2       3       4       5     6         7       8 
1         2       3       4       5     6         7       9 
ANCNO1  ANCNO2  ANCNO3  ANCNO4   ANCNO5  ANSLKI
1         2       3       4       5     6 
output